# Why are questions about distribution off topic?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked some questions (eg https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10228/what-does-it-typically-cost-to-launch-a-hollywood-movie-in-a-foreign-country) about international distribution which weren't received well. Then @coleopterist pointed out that the FAQ specifically excludes questions about distribution (I admit I hadn't checked).

I was surprised to find that the topic of distribution is outside the scope. Not least because there are other questions where distribution related issues are addressed (for example: [What causes a high budget title to be direct-to-DVD?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/what-causes-a-high-budget-title-to-be-direct-to-dvd?rq=1) or [Why was there such a large gap between the US and UK release of Wreck-It Ralph?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10006/why-was-there-such-a-large-gap-between-the-us-and-uk-release-of-wreck-it-ralph?rq=1) or [Was Gremlins 2 the first film to re-adapt a scene for release on different media?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/was-gremlins-2-the-first-film-to-re-adapt-a-scene-for-home-video-release?rq=1))

Also, this seems like the ideal place to deal with the topic. Contributors here have a good range of knowledge about how movies were released as well as what is in them. Why not put it in scope?

Answer (score 4):

This intention was mostly meant to stray away questions about distribution in very specific markets e.g. "Where can I find a local Blockbuster to rent Avengers?"  Or "Why does my local target distribute 1 copy of a time of Unicorn Apocalypse".

I do admit it is a very broad line but the exceptions to the rule have been well received.

While the Gremlins question as well as the HIgh Budget question you point out are decent enough exceptions, I'm still not  entirely convinced on the Wreck-It Ralph one.

The initial thoughts were to keep *any* topics of distribution that could be considered "Too Localized" out of the site.

As always, when an exception is brought up, I try to be as open minded as possible about it.

Your question in particular is an edge case at best because there could be a few good explanations to it but the possibility is even greater that discussion can crop up about specific costs as well as other marketing items that seem out of scope for this site.

That's my 2 pence

Comment: Unicorn Apocalype?

Comment: Yes, it was the major blockbuster of the year 2014.  Didn't you hear about it?