# Improving off-topic descriptions - particularly 'distribution'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

So we have had a recent interesting question about [film-distribution](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21224/what-is-the-relationship-between-theaters-and-film-distribution).

Strictly speaking 'distribution' is on the off-topic list, but we have a [distribution](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution) tag and a number of questions relating it it - so clearly its not actually off-topic.  If you look at [this related meta question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/899/why-are-questions-about-distribution-off-topic) you can see that the intent of this is to try to avoid 'purchasing questions' rather than good questions about how the movie distribution business works.

The current help for allowed/disallowed topics is:

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Movies & TV Stack Exchange is for Movie & TV enthusiasts and experts
>   alike!
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Analysis of content or theme of all forms of Movies/TV
> - Identifying a Movie or TV series (see below for details)
> - Questions about a Movie/TV show's production.
> - The works of a director / an actor / a writer related to
>
> Movies/TV Movies also includes Made-For-TV movies, Direct-to-DVD, and
>   Mini-Series.
>
> Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:
>
> - **Distribution**
> - Movie/TV purchasing/viewing locations
> - The operation of playing a movie whether it be digital or physical format.
> - Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.
> - TV news and current affairs
> - A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.
> - Opinions about or recommendations for a movie or TV show

Can anyone suggest improvements to the wording of these on/off-topic descriptions, particularly "Distribution" so that it more closely matches the intent.

Comment: As we all know web-series are allowed here then why not add them in On-topic section. Because soon their are so many superhero web-series coming and they will surely get us few good content.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is to drop "Distribution" entirely from the off-topic list and to improve the descriptions about locating, purchasing or playing content.  For good measure, I'm suggesting we also add sports to the news and current affairs lines, as this is a big area of TV that we don't address in the list.

My suggested list is below, additions or changes in bold:

> - **Locating or purchasing Movies or TV content**
> - **Technology questions about playing content**
> - Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.
> - TV news, **sports** and current affairs
> - A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.
> - Opinions about or recommendations for a movie or TV show

Answer (score -1):

I agree with iandot's suggestions, but I would modify the acceptable portion as such:

> If your question generally covers …

```
Analysis of content or theme of all forms of Movies/TV
Identifying a Movie or TV series (see below for details)
Questions about a Movie/TV show's production (see below for details)
```

> Production
>
> If your question is about what is involved in the distribution of a movie/tv show, such as how movies get to the theaters, it is on topic. If your question is about how to locate a certain movie on DVD, it is not on topic. See [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21224/what-is-the-relationship-between-theaters-and-film-distribution) for an example.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: I don't think that additional production paragraph is necessary and in the presented form it is far too example-based and narrowing, I think. The bad kind of distribution is laready covered in the off-topic section and just limiting the extra production paragraph to outruling it again seems very inappropriate.